# How to get accuracy for Latitude and Longitude values by using Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gps, arkit, indoor-positioning-system

Hi I am using the below code to the get the Latitudes and Longitudes form an IOS device.The problem is I am getting only upto four points.So I read in blogs we need to use double to get more decimal points and Unity API only supports 4 decimal points or upto 6 decimal points for latitudes .In order to get accurate Lat/Long values we require more decimal points.(Eg:8.8382738239232032,120.23232328347823782323).How to get more decimal values.

```
void Start ()
{
    StartCoroutine(Getdata());
}



IEnumerator Getdata()
{
    // First, check if user has location service enabled
    if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
        yield break;


// Start service before querying location
Input.location.Start();

// Wait until service initializes
int maxWait = 20;
while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    maxWait--;
}

// Service didn't initialize in 20 seconds

if (maxWait < 1)
{
    print("Timed out");
    yield break;
}
// Connection has failed
if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
{
    print("Unable to determine device location");
    yield break;
}
else
{




    double aa= Input.location.lastData.latitude;
    Debug.Log("Double Latitude="+aa);

    latitudes = double.Parse(Input.location.lastData.latitude.ToString("R"));
    longitudes = double.Parse(Input.location.lastData.longitude.ToString("R"));
    altitudes = double.Parse(Input.location.lastData.altitude.ToString("R"));
    deviceinfo = SystemInfo.deviceModel;
// Access granted and location value could be retrieved
Locationinformation.text = "Location: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " + Input.location.lastData.timestamp;
print("Location: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " + Input.location.lastData.timestamp);
}

// Stop service if there is no need to query location updates continuously
Input.location.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know of 2 option here:
Either use an additional asset like this one [accura-gps-for-unity](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/accura-gps-for-unity-122437)
or get the values that are picked up in iPhone_Sensors.mm then you convert them into a string, and finally pass them into Unity. Use this guid [PluginsForIOS](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html)

Comment: How to get the values from iPhone_Sensors.mm. You mean I have to create a plugin for unity?iPhone_Sensors.mm Where to find it?